# Requirements to use 55W Bi-xenon 6000k projector on yamaha r15 v 2.0

Tags: motorcycle, headlight, yamaha, hid

I have a problem with my vehicle headlights. Now I'm using a 35W 8000k projector for my bike. This is not having much light output as I wish. I'm really interested to see powerful light  output from my ride like the light output comes from cars. Not much of that but at least good lighting.

- Can I use 55w/60w bixenon projector instead of my 35w one?
- What all should I do to upgrade?
- Is this upgrade possible?

Answer (score 2):

**I would be concerned with your stator and your battery**

Both your stator and your battery will have additional load on them.

If your stator can feed your batter under these circumstances then the batter may have a bit of a reduced life but can more than likely handle the extra 25 - 30 watts.

My primary concern would be the extra heat generated by the stator under these circumstances.  Heat is a bi-product of electric generation, call it waste.  This heat will increase the temperature of the windings and possibly accelerate the decay of the insulation protecting the windings from touching each other and grounding out your stator.  Additionally, your rectifier will experience additional heat and would experience a degraded lifetime as well.

I would suggest using LED lights that would consume less wattage and potentially give you increased light and visibility you are attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly **YES** you can do it.

But beware you will definitely reduce the life of your battery since it will be difficult for it to handle Bi xenon low at 60w.

Upgrade your battery(Possibly higher AMP rating) also make sure while initial installation all the wiring is properly done since a short circuit on a 60w projector will burn through your reflector.